# Rails Devise - Validate password field when using update_without_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed instructions on the Devise wiki to allow users to edit their account without providing a password:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

I still have the password and password_confirmation fields in my form. I just don't want a user to have to enter their current password. How can I still force validation over these two fields when using the update_without_password function?

```
def configure_account_update_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :locale, :time_zone, :phone, :password, :password_confirmation]
end

def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

Comment: Just a tip- it's not good practice to let users change their passwords without providing current password. For ex. I've made a whole different action with different view for changing pswd and `current_pswd` is also required there. Thatway you can avoid use case where user leaves his/hers account open and walks away from computer and sb could gain control over user's account by changing it's password.
But ofc- I'm not familiar with your application and maybe it's not relevant in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I still force validation over these two fields when using the update_without_password function?

***I think what you should do is create a [`custom validation method`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) and call it only for update method.***. You can achieve it by doing something like this:

```
#user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_password_fields, on: :update

  def validate_password_fields
    errors.add(:base, "Please enter correct values") if password.blank? || password_confirmation.blank? || (password != password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this idea! I added this in and the error message "Please enter correct values" is now always shown, so it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @MollyHarper what do you mean by always showing? Does it show up when a new user register? Are you using *on:* option which will fire up that method only when a user update his/her account